# Wait for a thread to join with time limit

Tags: multithreading, c++11, asynchronous

I've got a thread that invokes a function `MyFunc` with parameters `params`. Basically it outputs dots in a stream while `MyFunc` is running, with timeout 500 ms. I need to wait for a thread for 1 minute, then I need to output either *"MyFunc successfully completed"* if the function finishes its work within 1 min or *"Timeout"* if after 1 min it is still running. How can I do that ?

```
std::future<void> f = std::async(std::launch::async, MyFunc, params);

std::chrono::milliseconds span(500);
while (f.wait_for(span) == std::future_status::timeout)
    std::cout << '.';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `wait_for()`,without a problem.

```
std::future<void> f = std::async(std::launch::async, MyFunc, params);


auto because = std::async(std::launch::async,[&]() 
         {
           // for your use, you may want to change it from 0 seconds to something
           // like 1 second, or 500 ms
           while(f.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) != std::future_status::ready)
               std::cout << ".";
         }).wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(60));

if(because == std::future_status::ready) 
  std::cout << "Successfully Completed\n";
else
  std::cout << "Timeout";
```

Comment: holy majoly, are you 16 ? what did i do when i was 16. i ate dirt

Answer (score 0):

Remember when you started waiting, or count the number of times you waited. Then you check those values on each iteration and determine whether more than 1min has passed. In that case you exit the loop.